# WcfTestClient: Failed to add a service. Service metadata may not be accessible

Tags: c#, xml, wcf

at the beginning sorry for my English.

I know that there are already answers for this question but none of them worked for me.
I am trying to connect to my database.

I am working on:

- Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2015 version 14.0.25431.01 Update 3.
- Microsoft .NET Framework Version 4.6.01586

I have already checked Tools->Options->Project and Solutions->Web Projects->Use the 64 bit version of IIS Express for web sites and projects.

My code from View Markup (Service1.svc):
*<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="WCFconnection.Service1" CodeBehind="Service1.svc.cs" %>*

here is my Web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=XXXXXXXXXXXX" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2" />
    <httpModules>
      <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" />
    </httpModules>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>   
      <service name="WCFconnection.Service1"
           behaviorConfiguration="metadataBehavior">
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="WCFconnection.IService1" />
        <endpoint address="basic" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="WCFconnection.IService1" />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <endpoint address="localhost:23233/Service1.svc"
              binding="basicHttpBinding" 
              contract="WCFconnection.IService1"
              />
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior  name="metadataBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
        </behavior>
        <behavior  name="DefaultBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
      <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <remove name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" />
      <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" preCondition="managedHandler" />
    </modules>
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
  </system.webServer>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ZPIEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model1.csdl|res://*/Model1.ssdl|res://*/Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=XXXXXX-XXXXXX;initial catalog=XXXXXX;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
    <add name="ConStr" connectionString="Data Source=XXXXXXX-XXXXXXXX\XXXXXXX;Initial Catalog=XXXXXXX;Integrated Security=True"/>
  </connectionStrings>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

When I go to website and put localhost:23233 into address I can see all the files, also my Service1.svc. But if I try to make WcfTestClient I got error:

*Failed to add a service. Service metadata may not be accessible. Make sure your service is running and exposing metadata.*

*Error: Cannot obtain Metadata from http://localhost:23233/ If this is a Windows (R) Communication Foundation service to which you have access, please check that you have enabled metadata publishing at the specified address...*

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error that WcfTestClient is giving you, you are not providing the full endpoint url.

You are adding `http://localhost:23233/`

You should be adding `http://localhost:23233/Service1.svc`

Comment: But in Web.config it is  already *<endpoint address="localhost:23233/Service1.svc"* Should I provide this endpoint somewhere else ?

Comment: Your Wcf **service** configuration seems to be fine. What is failing is how you add it to the WcfTestClient (or any other place where you consume it, I guess). When you open WcfTestClient and hit "Add" to add a new service endpoint you should pass the full endpoint url, not just the address and port. This is because you can have multiple endpoints on one address and port.

Comment: I did as you mentioned and I have the same error:

*Error: Cannot obtain Metadata from http://localhost:23233/Service1.svc If this is a Windows (R) Communication Foundation service to which you have access, please check that you have enabled metadata publishing at the specified address. *

Comment: OK now strange thing - if I delete all the endpoints from Web.config then WcfTestClient works fine... 
But I think it should NOT stay like this... Should it?